# In Design Horizontal Black lines in PNG that shouldn't be there and get printed!

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've got a slightly different problem.
I've got horizontal lines (like exercise book lines but much closer together) behind ONE image on a page full of several copies of said image.
There is a gradient background.
Now if it only affected one box I'd understand (maybe) but after searching with no success to an answer, I tried exporting again.

Each time I export it **the Bounding box that contains said lines changes**.
Even my screen can't always decide if they are there or not (which was mentioned earlier I know), **my printer can 'see' them perfectly well AND prints them off**!

How do I stop this?
The lines are directly under the Gradient and fade out at the edges where the gradient stops.
Please help!

Comment: I have no clue what this is trying to convey. I'd suggest you *slow down* and try to be a bit more clear. Realize no one here can see what you see. You talk about "exporting" then "printing" so it's all just a mess in a wall of text.

Comment: Take it apart. If you remove the `.png` and nothing else, does it stop? If so... see if the image is good. Preview it in another application. Open it in Photoshop. If it looks corrupted, replace it. Even if the `.png` looks fine in any other application save it again in Photoshop. Maybe try another format, like `.tiff`. Also maybe see if re-linking to any other image (maybe `.png`) changes anything. If some other graphic element is causing it, re-create it.